# Use angular hash routing in callback url for 3 legged auth

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm setting up 3 legged authentication with Forge. Our frontend is written in Angular and we use hash routing.

I'm trying to enter http://localhost:4200/#/forge/callback as the callback url in my forge application settings. It appears anytime i include a hash the updates fail to save.

Anyone else had any luck with hashes in callback urls?

Comment: I reported that behavior to the development team... In the meantime I don't see a workaround other than not using hash character in your Forge callback URL route. If you are using node/express it would be rather straightforward to handle the route setup on the server side, for example with an /api route which will be first picked up server side and then if no route is matched it will default to your client route. You can find such an example in my sample at https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/blob/master/src/server/index.js#L167

Comment: Thanks Philippe!

I did find a work around if any other Angular devs are looking.

I put a static html file in the assets folder that I can access from locahost:4200/assets/page.html. That page accepts the request from Forge and forwards the parameters to my component page.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Ben